# Why is JMS changing my Doctrine Entity boolean values?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

This is the first time I've needed to ask a question - I usually find the answer..

I am able to convert a Doctrine entity to and from JSON with JMS Serializer.  My only problem is that when i deserialize from JSON back to the entity, any false boolean values: `"boolean_value":false` in the JSON will be set as `true` in the Doctrine Entity.

I have narrowed it down to the JMS Serializer.  The data is changed in this code.

```
public function toEntity($entity_name, $input,  $inputFormat = 'json') {
    // $input is a json string where "boolean_value":false
    $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
    $entity = $serializer->deserialize($json, $entity_name, $inputFormat);
    // the output entity's $boolean_value is now true
    // $entity->getBooleanValue() === true
    return $entity;
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out json_decode does not convert the string values of 'true' or 'false' to `true` or `false`, so the code checked whether the string value was true|false.

[PHP: Booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

I updated my toEntity method to fix this problem.

```
public function toEntity($entity_name, array $input, $inputFormat = 'json') {
    foreach ($input as $k => $v) {
        if ($v == 'true' || $v == 'false') {
            $input[$k] = filter_var($v, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
        }
    }
    $input = json_encode($input);
    $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
    $entity = $serializer->deserialize($input, $entity_name, $inputFormat);
    return $entity;
}
```